# Mule4 studio error Cannot delete existing folder

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I am trying to run my Mule4 app in Anypoint studio. However, it started throwing below error:

- Failed to deploy artifact '000005107-http-basic-auth', see below
  Cannot delete existing folder

This error occurs only when I add property file, it works well if I remove property file.

Comment: Can you maybe put a screenshot of before and after and as well the stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running in Windows, there may be some other process using the target directory. For example, if you opened a command line window in the same directory, or an antivirus software. Usage of the target directory prevents Studio from deleting it to deploy the updated application.